# Laravel, what is the best/alternative way to check if record exists and display them within table?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5.4

Currently im using Laravel-Excel (MaatWebsite) and wanted to check whether excel data is same with data in database "furnitures" table

**Controller**

```
// assume $id is retrieve from parameter
$check_furnitures = Furniture::where('company_no', $id)->get();
$rows = Excel::load('storage\\app\\public\\upload\\furniture.xlsx', function($reader){$reader->noHeading();$reader->skipRows(1)})->get();
```

**View**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Chair Name></td>
      <td>Desk Name></td>
      <td>Carpet Name></td>
      <td>Status</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php $arr = array(); ?>
    @foreach($rows as $key => $value)
      @foreach($check_furnitures as $fur)
        @if(
           $fur->chairs == $value[1] && 
           $fur->desks == $value[2] && 
           $fur->carpets == $pvalue[3]
           )
          <?php $temp_array[] = $value[0] ?>
        @endif
      @endforeach
    @endforeach
    <tr>
      <td>{{$value[1]}}</td>
      <td>{{$value[2]}}</td>
      <td>{{$value[3]}}</td>
      <td>
        @foreach($arr as $test)
          @if($test == $value[0])
            DUPLICATED VALUE
          @endif
        @endforeach
      </td>
    <tr>
<table>
```

**Excel File**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way is to index your database results first instead of looping. Laravel has a `$collection->keyBy('id')` so that you can `$collection->get($id)` later.

Having said that, you can do it this way:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Chair Name></td>
            <td>Desk Name></td>
            <td>Carpet Name></td>
            <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @php

        $arr = array(); 
        $check_furnitures->keyBy('number');

        @endphp
        @foreach ($rows as $key => $row)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $row->chair }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->desk }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->table }}</td>
                <td>
                    @if($check_furnitures->get($row->number) !== null)
                        DUPLICATED VALUE
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ok i understand, but do you know how do i get the id of table value? as you can see the picture i post, "Chair-abc" belongs to id of "32" in table furnitures, while "Chair-123" belongs to id of "42" in table funitures as well...and so on. Do you know how to get its id in views? I'm thinking to do as @if($check_furnitures->get($row[1]) !== null)

Comment: my advice is, you cannot rely on just number sequence to check if it exist. best is to include a column of ids on your excel file so you can check inparallel to the database.